# UITextField in ScrollView doesnt display keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have 10 textfield in a `UIView`, and I have added the view to a `scrollView`. In that 5 textFields will be displayed, and other will be scrolled.

In my `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag>=4)
    {
        CGRect viewframe=contentsOfView.frame;
        viewframe.origin.y=viewframe.origin.y-100;
        contentsOfView.frame=viewframe;

    }
}
```

And in my `textFieldDidEndEditing`

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if(textField.tag>=4)
    {
        CGRect viewframe=contentsOfView.frame;
        viewframe.origin.y=viewframe.origin.y+100;
        contentsOfView.frame=viewframe;
    }

}
```

The first 5 fields which are getting displayed in the screen works perfectly, if I scroll the screen for the next text field. If I tap in it, the keyboard doesnt appears.

```
[contentsOfView addSubview:nameField];
[contentsOfView addSubview:mobileNumberField];
[contentsOfView addSubview:passwordField];
[contentsOfView addSubview:taxiNumberfield];
[contentsOfView addSubview:emailIdField];
[contentsOfView addSubview:taxiTypeField];
[contentsOfView addSubview:licenseNumber];
[contentsOfView addSubview:nricNumber];
[contentsOfView addSubview:noOfPassengerField];
[contentsOfScrollView addSubview:contentsOfView];
 [self.view addSubView:contentScrollView ];
```

TextField

```
 nameField.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleLine;
nameField.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
nameField.layer.borderColor=[[HexColorCode colorWithHexastring:@"c88202" ] CGColor];
nameField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad;
nameField.placeholder=@"NAME";
nameField.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
 UIView *  paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 20)];
nameField.leftView = paddingView;
nameField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
nameField.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
nameField.delegate=self;
nameField.tag=1;
```

Comment: Can you show how you add the textfields to your view ?

Comment: Well ok, hmm, i guess i was a bit vague. Can you show how you create those textfield, and especially their frame ?

Comment: Are u using storyboards...?

Comment: no, fully code, please see my question u can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the contentView add the objects to the contectScrollView

```
[contentScrollView addSubView: nameField];
[self.View addSubView:contentScrollView];
```

This may help u.